# How to debug intermittent errors from Django app served with gunicorn (possible race condition)?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a Django app being served with `nginx`+`gunicorn` with 3 `gunicorn` worker processes.  Occasionally (maybe once every 100 requests or so) one of the worker processes gets into a state where it starts failing most (but not all) requests that it serves, and then it throws an exception when it tries to email me about it.  The `gunicorn` error logs look like this:

```
[2015-04-29 10:41:39 +0000] [20833] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 196, in get_response
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 226, in handle_uncaught_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1271, in _log
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1281, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1321, in callHandlers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 749, in handle
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 122, in emit
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 125, in connection
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 29, in get_connection
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
  File "/home/django/virtualenvs/homestead_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.core.mail.backends.smtp: "No module named smtp"
```

So some uncaught exception is happening and then Django is trying to email me about it.  The fact that it can't import `django.core.mail.backends.smtp` doesn't make sense because `django.core.mail.backends.smtp` should definitely be on the worker process' Python path.  I can import it just fine from a `manage.py shell` and I do get emails for other server errors (actual software bugs) so I know that works.  It's like the the worker process' environment is corrupted somehow.

Once a worker process enters this state it has a really hard time recovering; almost every request it serves ends up failing in this same manner.  If I restart `gunicorn` everything is good (until another worker process falls into this weird state again).

I don't notice any obvious patterns so I don't think this is being triggered by a bug in my app (the URLs error'ing out are different, etc).  It seems like some sort of race condition.

Currently I'm using `gunicorn`'s `--max-requests` option to mitigate this problem but I'd like to understand what's going on here.  Is this a race condition?  How can I debug this?

Comment: Are you running out of resources/RAM? I notice in the gunicorn docs for the `--max-requests` it says *"Any value greater than zero will limit the number of requests a work will process before automatically restarting. This is a simple method to help limit the damage of memory leaks."* which might describe why this seems to fix the issue - you might have a memory leak somewhere (or just be using too much memory)

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I still have several hundred MB of RAM free, and memory usage isn't increasing over time, so I don't think it's a leak...  I'll look into it again though.

Comment: @JoeDoherty Django 1.6, unfortunately.  I've been kicking the upgrade can down the road but maybe this is a good time to bite the bullet and upgrade to 1.8.  Do you think that could help this issue out?

Comment: Can you set debug=True and then instead of emailing you see the error message on the web screen?  Alternately, did you try swapping out the smtp backend for dummy (or whichever one just dumps to the log file what it would have sent over email); that will probably get the same error but should be a quick enough check.

Comment: @Foon I rarely see the error personally since they happen so infrequently...  This is a production site that would probably just scare customers if they saw a Djano error page :).  Regarding using another email backend, I'll give it a try but I agree that it will probably give the same type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered one particular view that was pegging the CPU for a few seconds every time it was loaded that seemed to be triggering this issue.  I still don't understand how slamming a gunicorn worker could result in a corrupted execution environment, but fixing the high-CPU view seems to have gotten rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Sentry which gives a smart way of handling errors.

You can use it as a cloud based solution ([getsentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/)) or you can install it on your own server ([github](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry)).

Before I was using django core log mailer now I always use sentry.

I do not work at Sentry but their solution is pretty awesome !